# Radio button response slow in android browser or webview

Tags: android, performance, radio-button

I am creating a web application on android which collect information about people going in to train station. I have used radio button and I find that the response of the radio button is really slow. I need extremely fast respond as there may be multiple of people passing at the same time. Here is my php code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" id="gender1">Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" id="gender2">Female<br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="1" id="age1">< 18<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="2" id="age2">19-29<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="3" id="age3">30-39<br>
    <input type="radio" name="age" value="4" id="age4">> 40<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>

<!--ajax form submit to be completed-->
```

There is a delay when I tap on the radio button, also, when I tap on different radio buttons fastly (press Male and immediately press > 40), it didn't response correctly (only the < 40 radio is checked), is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: It seems that the radio button response only after the tap highlight effect finish, any way to disable it? -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); can only hide the color but not disable the effect